# Generate a dictionary from a file of key-value pairs separated by semicolon

Tags: python

I'm importing some data from a file in this format:

```
username:password;username1:password1;username2:password2;
```

I need to import this into a dictionary and make the `key = username` and `value = password` etc

What i got so far is:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    password_list = dict(x.strip(":").split(";", 1) for x in f)


for user, password in password_list.items():
    print(user + " - " + password)
```

The results comes out as `username:password - username1:password1`. So I need to split them again. any tips?

Comment: Add another for loop?

Comment: so basically your file has only one line?

Comment: yes sir. One line containing thousands of values that are usernames and passwords. Trying to get users to become keys and passwords to become values so i can do operations on them like for example finding duplicates and such

Answer (score 1):

you need to hierarchize your split operations:

```
s = "username:password;username1:password1;username2:password2"

d = dict(v.split(":") for v in s.split(";"))

print(d)
```

result:

```
{'username2': 'password2', 'username': 'password', 'username1': 'password1'}
```

for a multi-line file, just add one more loop:

```
d = dict(v.split(":") for s in f for v in s.strip().split(";"))
```

It's worthy to add that:

- such a format is short-lived if password contains `;` or `:`. Using the `csv` module and proper quoting could solve the issue
- duplicate usernames are ignored: only the last entry is considered because of dictionary key unicity.
- `dict(v.split(":") ...)` construct is the old way to create a dictionary without dictionary comprehension, particularly useful here since `split` returns a `list` of *exactly* 2 values (key/value).

Comment: that would work on such a list, but not a file being read in a dictionary

Comment: Very nice, if we use `dict` instead of dictionary comprehension we can assign a key and value at same time using one expression that couples the `keys and values` such as `split(':')` was not aware, ty

Comment: @HannaL. you can either read the file as `str` first or do it directly on `f.read().split(';')` since you said the file is just one line.

Comment: `for line in file` gives strings with trailing newlines, probably don't want to include them in that last password

Comment: hence the `s.strip()` in the second snippet

Answer (score 0):

You could first split on the `";"` character and for each of the retrieved values split on the `":"` character.

Suppose input is defined as this

```
input = "username:password;username1:password1;username2:password2;"
```

This we can create a dictionary with this

```
dict([entry.split(":", 1) for entry in input.split(";") if entry])
```

#### Explanation

First we split on each `username:password` entry

```
[entry for entry in input.split(";")]
```

Then we check whether there are no empty entries

```
[entry for entry in input.split(";") if entry]
```

Then we split each entry on the first `":"` character

```
[entry.split(":", 1) for entry in input.split(";") if entry]
```

And finally we put it in a dictionary

```
dict([entry.split(":", 1) for entry in input.split(";") if entry])
```